# Unable to create sql table with Presto

Tags: sql, presto

I'm really trying to get going with sql but can't even create a simple table. I've been working on this for the past two hours and can't get going. I know the solution is easy and everyone laughs, but where is the syntax wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1
(
state varchar(10),
city varchar(10),
);
```

The error reads `line 2:1: mismatched input '(' expecting AS`.

When I add `AS`:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 AS
(
state varchar(10),
city varchar(10),
);
```

`line 3:1: no viable alternative at input 'state'`

I've tried about 14 other combinations of `AS` and curly braces `{` , `TEMPORARY TABLE` with others and can't solve it. There has to be something I'm missing.

Comment: Hi what was the issue for this ...

Answer (score 1):

There is extra comma ","  just before ")"

Run below code.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1
(
state varchar(10),
city varchar(10)
);


CREATE TABLE tbl1
(
state varchar(10),
city varchar(10)
);
```

Comment: I received the same error `line 2:1: mismatched input '(' expecting AS`